# How do I send a data from Validator::extend() to Validator::replacer() so that my message can be more detailed?

Tags: validation, laravel-5, httpresponse

I'm validating the contents of a csv with a custom validator to ensure that the rows and cells are all valid.  When I find an error - I want the message to be specific.  Is there a way to send information from Validator::extend() to Validator::replacer() ?

Unfortunately my company infra is not good, so I don't have sessions or redis or anything.  Pure php/laravel solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your validation() and your replacer() in a class together, then pass data between them using the properties of that class.  That's the simple part.  However, that class must be a singleton produced by a factory because if it isn't, then the call to validate() and the call to replacer() will each get their own instance and the properties will be new each time.

In App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php add something like this to the boot() method.

```
Validator::extend('myRuleName', 'App\Validators\MyCustomValidatorClass@validate');
Validator::replacer('myRuleName', 'App\Validators\MyCustomValidatorClass@message');
```

Same AppServiceProvider file, inside the register() method.  Force laravel to always load the same instance of your validator by making it a singleton.  This is the key to having $persistant_info.

```
$this->app->singleton(\App\Validators\MyCustomValidatorClass::class, function(){
        return new \App\Validators\MyCustomValidatorClass;
    });
```

Now create your MyCustomValidatorClass.php in app/Validators with this in it...

```
namespace App\Validators;

class MyCustomValidatorClass{

private $persistant_info = 'Foo';

public function validate($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator){
    $this->persistant_info = 'Bar';
    return false;//normal true/false validation of $value
}

public function message($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters){
    return $this->persistant_info; //returns Bar
}

}
```